# python on usb stick

Tags: python, portable-applications

Is there any free and open-source option to run python from an usb-stick on Windows system (i.e. python installed on an usb-stick ) and can run on any Windows system just by pluging-in the usb-stick?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/).

Comment: Can i install on it different packages if needed ?

Comment: Python on a stick, sounds delicious

Comment: @oren: yes, that should be fine.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. Portable Python site now says "Portable Python is not being developed anymore" and there is no download links, just links to other python distributions.